# tableofcontents depth in revtex4-1

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

The revtex style files override the usual tocdepth command, so it has no effect. From a previous post I learned how to DECREASE the tocdepth: For instance,

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@subsubsection#1#2{}
\makeatother
```

will turn off the subsubsection listing in the toc; it has the same effect as

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

would have in ordinary LaTeX. But I have the opposite problem: I want to turn ON the listing of paragraphs, i.e., I want to increase the tocdepth to 5. Does anyone know how to do that? I'm running revtex4-1 with the rmp document class.

Comment: Can you make a short example to play with?

Answer (score 0):

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{5.3em}{2.1em}}
\makeatother
```

before the `\tableofcontents` command does the trick.

Comment: Can you make a short example to show how this works?